# Get information from object (JAVA)

Tags: java, methods, parameters, set, hashset

So I have to make this object, DocumentAnalyzer, then in other functions, for example getUniqueWords, I have to be able to take the contents of the file saved in this, and sort through the contents. To get unique words I was going to use `Set`, as it cannot have duplicates.

Object:

```
public DocumentAnalyzer(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
      try
      {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
          records.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }

      System.out.print(records);
}


public Set<String> getAllWords(?????) 
{

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(values);

    for (String value : set)
        System.out.printf("%s", value);

    return set;
}
```

How do I make it so when I call the function it can use the information inside DocumentAnalyzer? I know it has something to do with the Parameters, so will I have to cast something? is it actually pretty simple I am just overlooking?
Been banging my head on this for hours

Comment: and yes I put the ???? there because I figure that is where my problem is!

Comment: Declare records outside any method, then use it inside getAllWords method, you don't need to pass anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is probably in a `class` declaration, such as:

```
public class DocumentAnalyzer {
    // your code here
}
```

Your current problem is that `List<String> records` is a local variable of your constructor.

What you need is to **store your information as a field** (a.k.a. attribute) of this class, instead of keeping your variable declaration in the constructor:

```
public class DocumentAnalyzer {

    private List<String> records;

    // your code here
}
```

Then, use that field instead of a local variable in the constructor, by replacing:

```
List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
```

By:

```
records = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now you don't need any parameter for your `getAllWords()` method, as you just have to use `records`, which is accessible from there.